# A Base page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Do you recommend from every web site created in Visual Studio, that you should create a Base page that serves as the parent class?

What are the exact benefits/drawbacks?

Comment: I don't think I've been giving an answer yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to override the way something in ASP.NET works, it can be more efficient to build it into a base class rather than including the code in every page. Two specific instances where I've done this are:

**IsPostback**
Little-known fact: it's quite feasible to craft a request that, to ASP.NET, looks like a postback but is submitted with a GET request. Who does this? Hackers, that's who. A call to `IsPostback` in this case will return `true`, but it shoud really return `false`. To get round this, build a base class that overrides IsPostBack:

```vb
Public Class MyBase
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    <DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Public Shadows Function IsPostback() As Boolean

        'Check the built-in IsPostback and make sure this is a HTTP POST
        Return (Page.IsPostBack AndAlso Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper = "POST")

    End Function

End Class
```

**Error Handling**
In [Beginning ASP.NET Security](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-ASP-NET-Security-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470743654/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1298043974&sr=8-1), [Blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525/blowdart) talks about the fact that if you use ASP.NET's error handling to redirect the client to a custom error page, hackers (again) can detect the redirection and flag it as an error that may be exploitable. A more secure pattern is to handle the Page's Error event and do a Server.Transfer (which doesn't send anything to the client). Again, doing this in a base class means you only write the code once:

```cs
public partial MyBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Error (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        // Do something with the exception e.g. log it
        ...

        Server.Transfer("~/mycustomerrorpage.aspx");
     }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an older post, but for people who might refer to this answer in the future, I'd better add this.  I would not put the error handling on the page base class' Page_Error event handler.  I would put it in the global.asax Application_Error event handler.  This way any error is caught and handled securely regardless of whether the page uses your base class or not.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I do.

But please remember that the purpose of a **base page** is totally different from the purpose of a **master page**.

Let me explain.

## Master pages

are layout elements used to share the same graphical features and part of the webforms behaviour (think a login/logout box with code-behind) across all pages that are associated to the master. Your final page classes will *include* a reference to the master page so the final result will appear as the master page *including* your page (check the source code to tell who contains whom)

## Base pages

are (abstract? at least not sealed!) classes from which all your pages inherit from the code-behind view. Unless you explicitly and **programmatically** add controls to the basae page, ie. in the constructor via `LoadControl` method, all pages will look blank from the very beginning until you add code.

But often they are useful. If you want to override some of the base class methods, you can have the overriden behaviour shared across all pages. Or, you may want to expose application-specific objects to the children pages (a reference to a data access layer, a logger or whatever). An example is overriding `UICulture` property to retrieve the user-preferred language from cookies.

## Both can be combined

Depending on your goals, you may combine master pages with base pages.

I suggest you to **always** create a base page class, since if your application's requirements change over time and you already created lots of pages, you can try to modify the base class to have the modifications propagated to all pages, according to the level of complexity of them.

Comment: Who said anything about master pages?

Comment: Matt answered about master pages. My answer completes the other one

Answer (score 1):

Check out masterpages this is their primary purpose.

Here's a link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

This will serve as the template for your site.  You would add a content section that would make up the body of your site.  You can reference the master page is your subpages to have a consistent layout, menu, etc. for you site.

Also, like the others have noted.  If you are running any commond code, just create a class a reference it from wherever you need it.

Comment: I know what Master pages do.  I'm talking about a Base page, that can sit inbetween a Web Class and a web page.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size and complexity of your project. For small websites with minimal functionality, a base page might be overkill. That said, I would typically use it for site-wide functionality, such as security. I tend to keep functionality in the master pages to a minimum since their primary purpose is to organize your layout and factor out common display areas from you content pages to avoid duplication and ease maintenance.

To create a base page for use in a master page scenario, you could use the following syntax:

**Master Page:**

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyProject.master.cs"
        Inherits="MyProject.MasterPages.MyProject" %>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">   
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Base Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MyProject.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BasePage.aspx.cs"
        Inherits="MyProject.BasePage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
    runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Content Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="MyProject - Home" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MyProject.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFileBaseClass="MyProject.BasePage" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
            Inherits="MyProject.Default"
                Meta_Description="Code Snippet: Master Page and Base Page"
                    Meta_Keywords="master, base, content" Theme="Style" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"
   runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Syntax also varies between Web Site and Web Application projects. Stay away from the former, it was only ever intended for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need common functionality on all your pages that belongs to the page class, create a common base class.

If you don't need such common functionality on all your pages, don't create a common base class.

If you can't decide, having a base class isn't going to hurt anybody, so you might as well have one (I'd say you more often end up needing some common functionality than not)