# Same method for all new Page's with override global method / event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have question from ASP.NET

on every aspx page I need to have similar action / method and I don't want replicate code.

My method is checking if user has Session, if he doesn't have - browser will go to Login Page.

Maybe I should use some global method?

```
public partial class FirstPage : Page
{

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sessionHelper = new SessionHelper();
        if (sessionHelper.isUserLogged())
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at adding a class that derives from `BasePage` that performs this common tasks and then have `FirstPage` (and the others) inherit from that.  Then just be sure so call `base.Page_Load(sender, e)`.  Here's an example [A Base page in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041675/a-base-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: There are many ways of setting up ASP.Net so that particular pages do/do not require authentication (and authorization) checks. Why are you not using these build in facilities? (I.e. old-skool asp.net uses the `<authorization>` element in web.config together with `<location>`. MVC allows you to place such cross-cutting concerns in action filters and the like)

Comment: Well I'll have to do that, but I am on first module of project, there is nothing about Authorization etc. so the solution is good for now.

Comment: Why don't you use a class?

Comment: Basically, that's the point of our conversation. To use class which will improve Page functionality.